# Select elements in cached jQuery object

Tags: jquery

Assume we were passed the following element:

```
var cachedElement = $('<div><p>Some text</p></div><aside>Some more text</aside>');
```

If I know what is in the element, I can easily traverse it. For example, to find the div I can use:

```
cachedElement.filter('div');
```

and to find a child element I can use:

```
cachedElement.find('p');
```

What if I do not know the structure of the cached element. How can I search for an element, which can be parent, child or both.

I was wondering if there is a method that can do that for me. I do not want to wrap the element in divs and search with .find().

My best solution is the following inefficient (and ugly) selector:

```
cachedElement.filter('selector_string').add(cachedElement.find('selector_string')).eq(0)
```

In my particular case i need only the first element.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to return the first html element in a string?

Comment: @FiveTools, i need to find an element in a jQuery object. I need a function similar to jQuery DOM selector, that i can use on a jQuery object which is not part of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take your original approach, and make it into a plugin if you wanted something a little cleaner:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.inclusiveFind = function( sel ) {
        return this.filter( sel ).add( this.find( sel ) );
    } 
})( jQuery );
```

Then call it like any other method:

```
var cachedElement = $('<div><p>Some text</p></div><aside>Some more text</aside>');

var div = cachedElement.inclusiveFind( 'div' ).eq(0);
var p = cachedElement.inclusiveFind( 'p' ).eq(0);
```

You may get a performance improvement by using the [`jQuery.merge()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) method:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.inclusiveFind = function( sel ) {
        return $.merge( this.filter( sel ), this.find( sel ) );
    } 
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why you would not want to wrap the content in a `div`:

```
$('<div />').append(cachedElement).find('selector_string').eq(0);
```

You *could* do something like:

```
cachedElement.find('*').andSelf().filter('selector_string').eq(0);
```

This will select *all descendants* of `cachedElement` and add `cachedElement`. So you would have selected all the elements in one jQuery object. But that seems rather inefficient to me as well.

Comment: I would like to avoid wrapping it in div.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I was not sure if there was some hybrid between .filter() and .find()

Comment: @Emil: No, there isn't. There are other ways (see my updated answer) but they are not necessarily better. Wrapping the content in a new element is quite good approach imo. I don't see a reason why you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: I am trying to avoid wrapping it in divs because i am doing multiple manipulations to the cachedElement. I am getting meta tags from data attributes, adjusting css, html and text before adding the element to the DOM. It is working, but the code is hard to scan. I was hoping that there was a handy selector I can use.

Comment: @Emil: I see. Well, sometimes it is better to write more verbose code than trying to keep everything compact. Go for the most readable version.